# Save a notebook with "input" and "output" on the left of all cells

Tags: notebooks, labeling, save, cells

How to make Mathematica save a notebook with "input 1" and "output 1" on the left of cells?
If I open a saved notebook, those tags are gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the value of the option [`CellLabelAutoDelete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellLabelAutoDelete.html) to `False`.  This can be done at the Cell, Notebook, or Global level.  This can be done using **Format** > **Option Insepctor...** or [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetOptions.html).

For one Notebook:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellLabelAutoDelete -> False]
```

Globally (overridden by Notebook options):

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, CellLabelAutoDelete -> False]
```